# Using the results of a select sub query as the columns to select in the main query. Injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a column storing sql functions, column names and similar snippets such as below:

ID | Columsql

1  |  c.clientname

2  |  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.DOB,103)

The reason for this is to use selected rows to dynamically create results from the main query that match spreadsheet templates. EG Template 1 requires the above client name and DOB. 
My Subquery is:

```
select columnsql from CSVColumns cc
left join Templatecolumns ct on cc.id = ct.CSVColumnId
where ct.TemplateId = 1
order by ct.columnposition
```

The results of this query are 2 rows of text:

c.clientname

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.DOB,103)

I would wish to pass these into my main statement so it would read initially

```
Select(
    select columnsql from CSVColumns cc
    left join Templatecolumns ct on cc.id = ct.CSVColumnId
    where ct.TemplateId = 1
    order by ct.columnposition
      ) from Clients c
```

but perform:

```
select c.clientname, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.DOB,103)  from clients c
```

to present a results set of client names and DOBs.

So far my attempts at 'injecting' are fruitless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, at least not directly. What you have to do is,  in a stored procedure, build up a varchar/string containing a complete SQL statement; you can execute that string.

```
declare @convCommand varchar(50);
-- some sql to get 'convert(varchar(10), c.DOB, 103) into @convCommand.

declare @fullSql varchar(1000);
@fullSql = 'select c.clientname, ' + @convCommand + ' from c,ients c;';

exec @fullSql
```

However, that's not the most efficient way to run it - and when you already know what fragment you need to put into it, why don't you just write the statement?

I think the reason you can't do that is that SQL Injection is a dangerous thing. (If you don't know why please do some research!) Having got a dangerous string into a table - e.g '`c.dob from clients c;drop table clients;`'- using the column that contains the data to actually execute code would not be a good thing!

EDIT 1:

The original programmer is likely using a C# function:

```
   string newSql = string.format("select c.clientname, {0} from clients c", "convert...");
```

Basic format is:

```
string.format("hhh {0} ggg{1}.....{n}, s0, s1,....sn);
```

{0} in the first string is replaced by the string at s0; {1} is replaces by tge string at s1, .... {n} by the string at sn.

This is probably a reasonable way to do it, though why is needs all the fragments is a bit opaque. You can't duplicate that in sql, save by doing what I suggest above. (SQL doesn't have anything like the same string.format function.)

Comment: I see why this appears inefficient (and dangerous) unfortunately the developer who created this system (which works) is unavailable, I'm butchering the code to allow us to use the "spreadsheet exporter" for other purposes.

The original read:
    Several WITH/CTE setups
    Select {0} from clients
    Left join CTEs

I'm just trying to replace the {0} with the 'injection'

Comment: I'm currently trying to find out what wizardry he used in the {0}, it appears to basically be the subquery I had earlier with something magical around it. I'm beginning to suspect it's built into the housing c# application to put in the desired parts before running the query against the database. If I find out, I'll let you know. Thanks for your time none the less.